# Regex - remove underscore and ampersand

Tags: c#, regex

My regex should allow a-z, A-Z, 0-9, single quote ('), space ( ), question mark (?), dash (-), full-stop (.).

The regex looks like this. But, it also flags underscore, ampersand as valid characters.

```
^[\.\w?\-&apos; ]+$
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z0-9' \?\-\.]` should be the correct string according to your request. the `\w` contains also `_` and the `&apos;` is copy/paste (unescape) error or it is 'valid' string? When it is 'valid' it represents a list of characters including ampersand character. Check your regular expressions on some online web debugging like https://regex101.com/ *(with explanations)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&apos;`inside a character class will match those characters literally. To match `'`, just use `'` literally.

As Srdjan M. commented, `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Resulting regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.?\-' ]+$
```

Try it online [here](https://regex101.com/r/nxm4Mi/1).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding the previous answers, 
if you want to match the escaped `'` as stated in the question then you can use

```
^(?:[\.a-zA-Z0-9.-\? ]|&apos;)+$
```

it uses a non capturing group `(?:exp1|exp2)+` to match one or more of exp1 or exp2 , as opposed to `[exp1exp2]+` which matches one or more of e or x or p or 1 or 2

you can try it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/FpXinV/4)